# select only rows with unique combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have a SQL query that's fetching a result like:

```
[{"id":89,"sender_id":2,"reciever_id":1,"message":"no reply","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20","updated_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20"},

{"id":88,"sender_id":1,"reciever_id":2,"message":"hiiiii","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:47","updated_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:47"},

{"id":87,"sender_id":5,"reciever_id":1,"message":"hiiiii","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:43","updated_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:43"},

{"id":86,"sender_id":1,"reciever_id":5,"message":"hiiii","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:38","updated_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:38"},

{"id":85,"sender_id":1,"reciever_id":5,"message":"hiii vRUN\n","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 16:10:51","updated_at":"2017-04-04 16:10:51"}]
```

But I want only unique combinations of `sender_id` and `reciever_id`. I need only 2 rows out of 5 because only 2 rows have unique combination. Like this:

```
[{"id":89,"sender_id":2,"reciever_id":1,"message":"no reply","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20","updated_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20"},

{"id":87,"sender_id":5,"reciever_id":1,"message":"hiiiii","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:43","updated_at":"2017-04-04 16:59:43"},
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: please update your queries'

Comment: 1- What is the criteria of the groupping
2- You can't group column like that unless you use an aggregate function like SUM(), MAX(),..
3- I am sure the question has already been answered in this website

Comment: i want the unique combination of sender_id and reciever_id,
so i need only 2 rows out of 5 because only 2 rows have unique combination

Answer (score 0):

add a **GROUP BY** like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( ,',',3),':',-1)
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('[{"id":89,"sender_id":2,"reciever_id":1,"message":"no reply","deleted_at":null,"created_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20","updated_at":"2017-04-04 17:01:20"},' ,',',3),':',-1) as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
| 1      |
+--------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```